# C++ merge sort problem while using dynamic array

Tags: c++, mergesort, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to implement a merge sort function but I have a problem with the merge part. Since initially, I don't know the array size, I created a temp dynamic array to store the final merged array. When I run this method, I get a Heap Corruption error. When I change the dynamic array size to (last + 1), the method runs without an error. I don't know why this causes a problem because the number of elements in the final array must be last - first + 1.

**My Merge Function**

```
void merge(int arr[], int first, int mid, int last) {
    int* temp = new int[last - first + 1];

    int first1 = first;
    int last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid + 1;
    int last2 = last;
    int i = first1;

    while (first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2) {
        if (arr[first1] < arr[first2]) {
            temp[i] = arr[first1];
            first1++;
        }
        else {
            temp[i] = arr[first2];
            first2++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    while (first1 <= last1) {
        temp[i] = arr[first1];
        first1++;
        i++;
    }

    while (first2 <= last2) {
        temp[i] = arr[first2];
        first2++;
        i++;
    }
    
    for (int k = first; k <= last; k++) {
        arr[k] = temp[k];
    }

    delete[] temp;
}
```

Comment: This is *much* easier if you forget the idea of first/mid/last and just use (a) pointer arithmetic to adjust to base address of your segment, and (b) a simple mid/len denoting the midpoint and length of the segment in question. It requires changing the mergesort algorithm, but the merge becomes trivial thereafter. It allows allows you to implement `mergesort(int *arr, size_t len)` (not there is no first, last; only a len).

Comment: [Example of above here](https://godbolt.org/z/ax7cq3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing `i`, which is used as the index for `temp` to `first1`, is bad because `temp` has only elements for the range between `first` and `last`.

`i` should be initialized to zero and the loop

```
    for (int k = first; k <= last; k++) {
        arr[k] = temp[k];
    }
```

should be

```
    for (int k = first; k <= last; k++) {
        arr[k] = temp[k - first];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even think that problem could be there.